# Concurrent connections per IP

Tags: firewall, redhat, apache-2.4, connection, netstat

I need to make a few changes to a firewall configuration, but before I do I'd like to see the number of concurrent Apache connections per IP. This command produces a nice list:

```
#netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n


 43 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 58 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
 99 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
115 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
132 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

I'd like to know for sure as to whether those counts are truly considered *cuncurrent* connections or not. Does the state of a connection affect concurrency? Would applying a grep for ESTABLISHED connections be more accurate?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `netstat -ntu` is such that it just prints any TCP or UDP connections registered in the connection table.  It does not differentiate based on state.  If you want to check for only established connections, you may want to start the command with:

```
netstat -ntu | grep "ESTABLISHED" | awk .....yaddayadda
```

You may also want TIME_WAIT connections, so you could do this:

```
netstat -ntu | grep "ESTABLISHED\|TIME_WAIT" | awk .....yaddayadda
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So if the state makes no difference can I be certain those counts are considered concurrent?